# Can anybody suggest a good link for a google glass tutorial?

Tags: google-glass

I tried to search but could not find a good one that explains everything, the links i found only provides some code snippets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of resources on Google Developers. Here are a couple notable ones:

- [An overview of the API](https://developers.google.com/glass/overview) - including some videos that describe what the API is capable of
- [Quick Start projects](https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/index) - Projects in Java, Python, PHP, .NET and Go that provide a turn-key starting point for developing with the Mirror API

Comment: Hey thats great, I managed to send some cards from the Google Mirror API Playground to my glass